# ADF PanelGroupLayout vs PanelGridLayout

Tags: oracle-adf

I am experiencing some delay in rendering part as my page contains lots of components like (inputs and labels etc). I have placed them in panelgridlayout.

I also used audit method in jdev there also found lots of time is taken by rendering.

So, I want to know which component will be the best or suitable for this. I also implemented panelGroupLayout (with horizontal and vertical) and panelfromlayout but has same slow rendering problem.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check how many layout managers you have inside of others. Too many layout managers inside one another can affect render speed.
PanelGroup Layout is for taking a "small" island of content and making its contents horiz, vertical - like buttons or fields or even groups of other islands of content - or add scroll bars if needed, like for a table.
PanelGrid layout is designed to layout a "larger" area and give the layout a grid and allow you to place items almost exactly where you want it.

Some layout managers are designed to layout "the whole page" - like PanelStretch, PanelSlider and PanelGrid, while others are for specialized tasks or group of content, like PanelGroup, FormLayout, Tab, Accordion.

So, depending on the layout, using PanelGrid may mean you do not need the others, and can simply free position all the item which may speed up rendering.
That said, there are many variables that affect rendering speed, and the complexity of the items on the ADF Faces page is *not* the first thing we look at - The ADF Model layer, how that is implemented and how the data source is tuned (or not) can be a bigger source of impact on rendering.

You did not specify version, that would help as well.

Before PanelGrid we tended to use PanelStretch or PanelSlider as the main window layouts that laid out the main sections of the page -  and put the other ones - panel group and formlayout inside it. With the advent of PanelGrid, some of this practice is no longer needed.

[This](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/adfarchitect-1639592.html), [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/layoutbestpractices-084287.html)  and [this](http://www.slideshare.net/maikorocha/designing-well-known-websites-with-adf-rich-faces) may help as well.